# Max MongoDB Connections when running with docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

I'm currently running MongoDB and Mongo Express with docker-compose. When I look on express, it shows I only have 815 available connections. How do I increase this? I tried adding 'command: maxConns 2000' in the docker-compose file but it had no impact. I believe MongoDB doesn't limit the number of connections so I assume this is a limitation`enter code here` with docker-compose?

version: '2'

services:

mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081

Answer (score 1):

Unless constrained by `maxConns`, mongo will calculate available connections based on **system** limits. [UNIX ulimit settings](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/) has guidance on checking and properly configuring ulimit values.